# Primefaces p:poll tag

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I am using the p:poll tag to display a live chart. I am using jfrecharts here so , basically the poll will update the image every 15 sec.

The problem is that i need to render an image soon as the page loads. But instead the poll delays from the first load. Is there any way to set the initial poll interval to Zero and for all other subseequent ajax calls poll with 15sec interval.

Regards,

Gayan

Comment: have you set autoStart=true ?

Comment: @Daniel yes , that will trigger the poll, but with the interval.

Answer (score 1):

Invoke same action method (of the `p:poll`) on page load
like described here:

[JSF 2 invoke action method on page load](http://itakeitalltheway.blogspot.com/2010/09/jsf-2-invoke-action-method-on-page-load.html)

---OR---

You can execute the same action of the `p:poll` on page ready , for example make a button with same action , make it hidden and on page load you can `.click()` on this button with jQuery.

---OR---

Set the interval value to something like `#{myBean.intervalValue}` , and setting `intervalValue` into zero , and on the pool method check if its zero and if its so set it to 15 (dont forget to update the `p:poll` itself so it will reevaluate the `intervalValue`)